# How does tf.estimator.LinearClassifier prediction work?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a TF model which is a `tf.estimator.LinearClassifier` built using the FTRL optimizer with L1 regularization. I have a sparse column with a couple of million of string keys and a couple of real valued columns.

The problem is that I want to extract the model trained and use it elsewhere, so I just took the weights resulted after training using `model.get_variable_value(var_name)` and plugged them in where I needed. The problem is I do not get the same results for identical examples, and it performs way poorly.

The way I am doing predictions is the standard way of multiplying the weights by the feature values, summing them up, adding the bias, and then applying the sigmoid function. For the keys in the sparse column the corresponding weight gets added only if the key is present in the current example.

My question is why am I not getting the same results. Is TF doing it differently? Is it using the weights in a different way to make predictions? If yes, then how.  PS. I have debugged this for over two day so I do not think there are bugs in my code.

Hopefully someone can clear the air on this, thank you!

Comment: Can you match tensorflow's predictions on an empty example (no features)? Can you match the predictions on an example with a single feature? With just the real-valued columns? Try doing this and you'll see what part of the behavior your code is not matching.

Comment: I actually figured it out. The problem was that I was using the 'sqrtn' combiner when creating the sparse column with keys. After I removed it I can use the weights outside of tensor flow with the same predictions.